# How to bind dynamic value to input using ng-repeat and ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing some problem while binding value to input in angular.I have initialized the 'object[component.name]' first and then I have assigned that value to ng-model. I have done like this because I have to bind the value from ng-repeat.but it gives me error. following is my code snippet.any help will be appreciated.

```
<div ng-repeat="component in reportTemplate" class="inputFieldSection inputFieldTitle" ng-if="component.type == 'text'">
                          <label class="item item-input">
                            <input type="text" name={{component.name}} ng-init="object[component.name]={{component.name}}"  ng-model="object[component.name]" ng-focus="clearValidation();" max-length="50" required placeholder="{{component.label}}">
                          </label>
                          <p ng-show="createReportForm.{{component.name}}.$error.required">Please Enter {{component.name}}</p>
                   </div>
```

Here is the error which I get in console

```
ionic.bundle.js:25510 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid  key at column 25 of the expression [object[component.name]={{component.name}}] starting at [{component.name}}].
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=…Bcomponent.name%5D%3D%7B%7Bcomponent.name%7D%7D&p4=%7Bcomponent.name%7D%7D
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13248:12
at Object.AST.throwError (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26061:11)
at Object.AST.object (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26048:16)
at Object.AST.primary (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25956:22)
at Object.AST.unary (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25944:19)
at Object.AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25931:21)
at Object.AST.additive (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25922:21)
at Object.AST.relational (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25913:21)
at Object.AST.equality (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25904:21)
at Object.AST.logicalAND (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:25896:21) <input type="text" name="{{component.name}}" ng-init="object[component.name]={{component.name}}" ng-model="object[component.name]" ng-focus="clearValidation();" max-length="50" required="" placeholder="{{component.label}}" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` directive should not have `{{}}`(interpolation directive) in it. You can access `createReportForm` object by using object `index`.

```
ng-show="createReportForm[component.name].$error.required"
```

Also `ng-init` has same mistake `ng-init="object[component.name] = component.name"`

> Not sure why you are using `ng-init` directive, it should be avoided.

Comment: The error seems to be in input field binding. I have tried what you have suggested but still got the same error.

Comment: @pritamkale error stack trace clearly indicating that, the error has happened on `input` field `ng-init` directive, try to change it like above I suggested. Thanks :)

Comment: @pritamkale did you able to make any progress on this?